# Setting a query result literal in Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to set a column result literal with the Laravel query builder. By writing raw SQL I would achieve this with:

```
SELECT
  `field1`, 
  `field2`, 
  'Test' AS `field3` 
FROM `Test`;
```

Therefore MySQL will always return Test for column field3. I'm trying to do this with the query builder like `select('field1', 'field2', '"Test" AS field3')` but this doesn't seem to work. It will return an error that Test is not a column name.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Comment: Didn't you mean `field3 AS Test`?

Comment: @Raphael_ No, he wants the string `Test` to be always the value of `field3` (which might not even exist).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `DB::raw()` function:

```
->select('field1', 'field2', DB::raw("'Test' AS field3"))
```